# Using postman with my passport API

Tags: express, passport.js, postman

I am building a rest api with express and passport, it successfully authenticates with the github strategy but i'm at a loose end trying to find how to use postman to test routes of my application that require authentication. Would really appreciate it if anyone has experience with postman in such a use case.

Thanks, Luke ;)

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using: http, SAML, oAuth, other?

Comment: I am using oauth 2

Comment: have you tried ["Auth" section](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/helpers) in request composer?